# Buttons extension not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use the [Buttons extension](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) from the Datatables. As said in the documentation, I've added this in my jQuery code :

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ]
} );
```

I have an ul appearing in my HTML for the buttons (with the classes "dt-buttons button-group") but this one is empty. Why is it empty?

Comment: I've tried on the live.datatables.net website, and there is still no buttons : http://live.datatables.net/hujizafo/1/edit?html,js,output. I must do something wrong

Answer (score 5):

Easy fix. Buttons has a lot of dependencies and you missed one.

You need to add this dependency if you're using HTML5 buttons (which you are):
`<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>`

See here: http://live.datatables.net/haceveko/1/edit

Comment: JSZip library is also required for HTML5 Excel button and pdfmake for HTML5 PDF button.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've seen in [this page](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html) (under the JS code) that you have to specifiy whether the buttons are in flash or HTML and add the files according to it

Comment: You do not have to specify the button genres, the data tables buttons plugin automatically, first tries if html5 button is suitable and then uses flash if not proper. Nothing if both are not usable for the page.